# How to receive templates from user to send a email?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, backend, email-templates

I'm making a service where a client of my service can decide what template they use when sending an email to a user.

I'm using pre-defined templates.

I'm working on node.js and using "email-templates" module for setting the template.

I want to receive the template from the client and use that template in sending their mail to give them a more personalized experience.

So, Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: Can you outline what you have tried? eg how are you receiving the templates? Do you have a way for the client to login? Are you using a framework?

Comment: Right now, I'm using a template file html.pug and I have that file inside my directory so client has right now nothing to do with templates and yes client have to login first to use that sevice . I'm using swagger 2.0 for documenting my api.What I want is that client give me template file and a client can add as much as template file as he wants and we can store that file in the databse.I've found the way like how to receive the file through swagger and save it into db but I,m confused with like what attributes should I use in the table I created for receiving the file?

Comment: I have never operated with a file inside the db.So I don't know what atrributes should i use in the schema and do we really need any attribute?